# How do I add a Deepsee Dashboard widget for autoupdate dashboard?

Tags: widget, refresh, dashboard, intersystems-cache

How do I add a Deepsee Dashboard widget for autorefresh dashboard?
I want to update chart values automatically.
Is it possible?
If yes, is there some code somewhere ?

Thanks in advance﻿

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control data updates within particular DeepSee widget.
Add **Refresh** control to a widget with type **Timer** and set timer interval for it.
[image: See the picture]

Comment: Mark my answer as answer please?